# What's the sure-fire way to check if a sensor exists and IS WORKING?

Tags: java, android, sensors

I've seen many methods on SO:

```
PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
boolean hasLightSensor = manager.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_SENSOR_LIGHT);
```

And another:

```
SensorManager sm = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
Sensor light = sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT);
if (light != null) {
...
}
```

And another:

```
SensorManager sm = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
Sensor light = sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT);
SensorEventListener listener = new SensorEventListener() {
     // create sensor listener
}
boolean hasLightSensor = sm.registerListener(listener, light, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
```

Comment: Can you please be more specific? What does "sure fire" mean to you? What is wrong with each of the approaches you've posted? Without knowing what your personal requirements are, I don't think there's a clear way to answer this.

Comment: @DV82XL I mean which of these methods checks if the sensor is working, not just exists according to manufacturer. How do I know if the user hasn't broken his light sensor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite a few classes and methods involved in Android sensor error handling. I've found that the best way to get clear answers is by looking at the source code, and sometimes that goes down a rabbit hole.

[SensorManager](https://java-browser.yawk.at/android/android-9.0.0_r35/android/hardware/SensorManager.java) is an abstract class that defines the methods to get the sensor list. `getDefaultSensor()`calls `getSensorList()`. If no sensors are found, `getDefaultSensor` will return `null`. The [Android Sensor Best Practices](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview#sensors-practices) page therefore recommends checking that sensors exist before using them, as follows:

```java
if (sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PRESSURE) != null) {
    // Success! There's a pressure sensor.
} else {
    // Failure! No pressure sensor.
}
```

You may also need to verify the return value of the `registerListener()` call. The [registerListenerImpl](https://java-browser.yawk.at/android/android-9.0.0_r35/android/hardware/SystemSensorManager.java#android.hardware.SystemSensorManager%23registerListenerImpl(android.hardware.SensorEventListener%2Candroid.hardware.Sensor%2Cint%2Candroid.os.Handler%2Cint%2Cint)) methods are implemented in [SystemSensorManager](https://java-browser.yawk.at/android/android-9.0.0_r35/android/hardware/SystemSensorManager.java), which is a concrete class that extends `SensorManager`. `registerListener` will:

- return `false` if any of the input arguments are invalid
- throw an `IllegalStateException` if `MAX_LISTENER_COUNT` has been exceeded
- return `false` if the sensor cannot be added to the `SensorEventQueue` associated with the provided `SensorEventListener`

This last point is important. The `BaseEventQueue` class (base class of `SensorEventQueue`) provides a method called [addSensor()](https://java-browser.yawk.at/android/android-9.0.0_r35/android/hardware/SystemSensorManager.java#android.hardware.SystemSensorManager.BaseEventQueue%23addSensor%28android.hardware.Sensor%2Cint%2Cint%29), which can return false if:

- the sensor has already been added to the queue and is active
- the sensor cannot support the provided batch report latency
- the sensor could not be enabled

This last point is very important, since a return value of `false` may indicate a sensor failure. To find out more about what can cause the sensor to not enable, you need to look into the [Native Sensor Manager](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/android-4.3_r2.1/core/jni/android_hardware_SensorManager.cpp) code in C++. Suffice it to say, you should always check the return value of your `registerListener()` calls. Don't forget to unregister when you're done with the sensor.

Comment: Thanks! I don't mind accuracy changes much tho. Just one question: If `sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PRESSURE) != null` does this mean that `registerListener` will always return `true`?

Comment: @User104163 I updated my answer to remove the calibration code and add more insight about `registerListener`. You do need to check its return value and I've provided some info why, and some references to the source code. Let me know if you have any other questions.